# some errors like Syntax error on token ";", @ expected

Tags: java, mysql

```
public class mysql {

private MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

// Set dataSource Properties
dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
dataSource.setPortNumber(3306);
dataSource.setDatabaseName("andrea");
dataSource.setUser("andrea");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
```

[this is the image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xj7L.jpg)I have some errors

Comment: This is not the right place, must be method or constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, everything needs to be wrapped in a method.

You can do something like:

public class MySQLConnector {

```
private MysqlDataSource dataSource;

public void connect() {
    this.dataSource = new MysqlDataSource()
    // Set dataSource Properties
    dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
    dataSource.setPortNumber(3306);
    dataSource.setDatabaseName("andrea");
    dataSource.setUser("andrea");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    // Continue from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not within any kind of method, you have placed it just within the class. I would recommend creating a constructor within your `MysqlDataSource` class so you can set all the values when instantiating the `dataSource` object.

For example you could do:

```
public class MysqlDataSource{

    public MysqlDataSource(String ServerName, String PortNumber, String DatabaseName, String User, String Password){
        this.ServerName = ServerName;
        this.PortNumber = PortNumber;
        this.DatabaseName = DatabaseName;
        this.User = User;
        this.Password = Password;
    }
}
```

Then within your `mysql` class you can write:

```
public class mysql {

    private MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource("localhost","3306","andrea","andrea","password");

}
```

You can read more about constructors [here.](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-a-constructor-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the properties of an object in that way.

Either set them inside constructor or method, or use instance(or static) block.

public class MySql {

```
private MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

{ **// This is an instance block**
    // Set dataSource Properties
    dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
    dataSource.setPortNumber(3306);
    dataSource.setDatabaseName("andrea");
    dataSource.setUser("andrea");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
}
```

}